# How to optimize RecyclerView for images with multiple width:height ratio to avoid jump/lag/jank?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, fresco

Our app is an image-heavy, fashion-centered app. Its Home screen contains an Instagram-like feed, which loads URL of images from the server and loads it using Glide.

Since we're using RecyclerView, the item is redrawn every time it leaves the screen. Problem is, this causes jank/lag every time user scrolls down (or up) and the RecyclerView needs to redraw the image (and then call `adjustViewBounds`) to make the image's width "fill" the screen width while keeping the ratio.

ImageView's XML code.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homeFeed_IV_lookImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:imageUrl="@{homeFeedItemViewModel.lookImage}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@drawable/static_image_1" />
```

Binding adapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun setImageUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String?) {
    if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        imageView.displayImage(url)
    }
}
```

Extension function.

```
fun ImageView.displayImage(url: String = "") {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.color.imagePlaceholder)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
            .into(this)
}
```

This "lag/jank" gives unpleasant experience. Is there any way we can make the image redraw in the RecyclerView smoother?

Comment: since your imageview adjusts it's height based on the aspect ratio and the width of the screen, you don't need to scale the image. Try removing android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to improve performance by using fixed sized ImageViews.
If you control the backend and have the possibility to include more information about the images than just the URL (so that you include width and hight or image aspect ratio in your feed payload).